# Added and removed a custom service, but the keybinding is still stuck?

Tags: macos, services

I created a custom service in Automator to open a new finder window from whatever app I'm in, and assigned it to CMD+E (I was trying to get the WIN+E effect from Windows.) I tried it for a few days, restarted the computer daily, but found it didn't work that well. So I removed the keybinding, then removed the service, deleted the Automator file, etc.

So, now the custom service is gone, but CMD+E still goes to the finder from whatever app I'm in! I added a custom shortcut to BBEdit in an attempt to restore its CMD+E action (find with selection), but it STILL goes to the finder! I just want CMD+E to do what it normally does in each app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file `~/Library/Services/NAME.wflow`.

---

Open `~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist` using *Property List Editor* from Apple's Developer Tools (or any third party software capable of opening binary `.plist` files).

Look for your service named `(null) - NAME - runWorkflowAsService` within `NSServicesStatus` and remove the entry.

Comment: There's nothing in `~/Library/Services/` and nothing in the `pbs.plist` file. I did see a file called `pbs.plist.C3TOD` which I deleted, but after restart the behavior is still there.

Comment: @Mathletics Does it behave like this for other user accounts too? (Create one if you need to)

Comment: no, just my account. (Sorry, I missed this response.)

Comment: @Mathletics How did you assign the keyboard shortcut? Via *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*? Be sure to also check the *Application Shortcuts* there.